# use KML , address lookup, directions and 'share map' on the same map

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, kml, bing-maps

I want to use my kml (or xml) file with places, but at the same time be able to search for places, use directions or 'share map' functionality. At the moment when I try to do that in Google or Bing, once I use KML file and search for a new place, I loose my KML placemarks..

Is there a way to do that with Google or Bing maps?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "lose" your KML placemarks. You mean they all disappear and are replaced by placemarks matching the user's search? Or something else?  Can you share your code so we can see what's going on? A link to your implementation if it's available on the Internet too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google can only handle one query at a time. There is no way of overlaying queries (IE you're KML and search term) by default.

You could do it yourself by using JavaScript and the Google Maps API.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/